# Screen has broken color set after a while - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, screen, monitor, color-management

After a while of no activity the screen locks, but when I log in the screen looks like this: 
:D

I am sure it is something with the software, not the hardware as I have never experienced similar thing on my other OS Windows 7 installed on the laptop beside my Ubuntu 14.04.

It is not often but I have to close programs, log out and then log in again so that the colours auto-repair them selves.

Previously I had Ubuntu 12.04 which was upgraded to 14.04. This didn't happen on 12.04

[image: ubuntu 14.04 monitor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some drivers don't respond well to returning from suspend. Turn that option off in System Settings -> Power:

[image: don't suspend]